# Build Query Builder by condition in Doctrine2. "Alias is already defined"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My code look like:

```
        if (isset($filters['price_from'])) {
            $queryBuilder
                ->leftJoin($root . '.variants', 'v')
                ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('v.price', ':price'))
                ->setParameter('price', $filters['price_from']);
        }

        if (isset($filters['price_to'])) {
            $queryBuilder
                ->leftJoin($root . '.variants', 'v')
                ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->lte('v.price', ':priceTo'))
                ->setParameter('priceTo', $filters['price_to']);
        }
```

I want to handle GET param to filter in my DB, but if there're both **price_from** and **price_to** param at a time, it throw exception 'v is already defined'. How can I manage to do that or is there a best practice to handle param to make filter? Thank your your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can group both conditions in order to call `leftJoin` only once.

```
if (isset($filters['price_from']) || isset($filters['price_to'])) {
    $qb->leftJoin($root.'.variants', 'v');

    if (isset($filters['price_from'])) {
        $qb->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('v.price', ':price'))
           ->setParameter('price', $filters['price_from']);
    }

    if (isset($filters['price_to'])) {
        $qb->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->lte('v.price', ':priceTo'))
           ->setParameter('priceTo', $filters['price_to']);
    }
}
```